# How to write Comp function in sort() of C++ STL

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, compare

In the code below, strArray is a array of strings, and vec contains corresponding ID of each string.
I want to sort IDs in vec based on strings in strArray.

How can I design the Comp function in sort?

```
class myClass
{
public:
        int V;
        vector<int> vec;
        string* strArray;

        myClass(int v);
        void myFunc();
}

myClass::myClass(int v, vector<int> vec1)
{
    V = v;
    strArray = new string[v];
    vec.swap(vec1)
}

void myClass::myFunc()
{
    //....

    for(i = 0; i<V; i++)
        strArray[i] = GenerateString(vec[i]);// GenerateString() can return a string.

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Comp);// sort vec based on strArray,how to design the Comp funtion?

    //....
}

main()
{
    int myints[] = {32,71,12,45,26,80,53,33};
    vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+8);

    myClass obj(8, myvector);

    obj.myFunc();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This appears to be a broken design. Given that you've ripped the code from the `std::sort` page at `cplusplus`, you've clearly already seen the docs. The sort function operates on elements in a container. The compare function takes in two variables - this is not suited to what you're trying to do. What about you keep a vector of structs? Each struct could hold a string and an integer. The compare function would then simply compare the integer member of the struct.

Answer (score 3):

Change member `string* strArray;` to `std::pair<std::string, int> strArray;`, change allocation `strArray = new std::pair<std::string, int>[v];` and make the following changes in your `myFunc`

```
void myClass::myFunc()
{
    //....

    for(i = 0; i<V; i++)
        strArray[i] = make_pair(GenerateString(vec[i]), vec[i]);// GenerateString() can return a string.

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    std::transform(
        strArray,
        strArray + V,
        vec.begin(),
        [](const std::pair<std::string, int> &p) -> int { return p.second; }
    );

    //....
}
```

In this code we couple or pair the number (`vec[i]`) that generated the string and sort the array. Now using `std::transform`, the number is copied back to the `vec`

**From comment**

If you don't understand lambda function, you can also write a function elsewhere and pass it as fourth argument in `std::transform`

```
static int fetch_int_from_pair(const std::pair<std::string, int> &p) {
 return p.second;
}
...
td::transform(
        strArray,
        strArray + V,
        vec.begin(),
        fetch_int_from_pair
    );
```

Comment: Hi Mohit,

Can you explain the following code for me? Thanks!
 "[](const std::pair<std::string, int> &p) -> int { return p.i; }"

Comment: @Jessica, it's a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Basically it's a small inline function to extract the second element of the pair. (I suspect it should be p.second here)

Comment: Hi MohitJain and shuttle87, I got it, both of you are so nice, thank you very much!